# Java - extracting a value from a JSON file

Tags: java, json, file-io

I have the following JSON text file:

```
{
  "quiz": {
    "q1": {
      "question": "Is this a test?",
      "options": [
        "TEST A",
        "TEST B",
        "TEST C",
        "TEST D"
      ],
      "answer": "TEST A"
    },
    "q2": {
      "question": "Are you sure?",
      "options": [
        "TEST A",
        "TEST B",
        "TEST C",
        "TEST D"
      ],
      "answer": "TEST C"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to write a program that is eventually able to take values from this file and display them in a GUI.

At the moment i have the following:

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/testing/Desktop/workspace/test1.txt"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj; 




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How exactly would i go about getting the value for "q1" "question"? I understand in JS i could just use `$.quiz.q1.question` but im unsure how to go about this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/testing/Desktop/workspace/test1.txt"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(obj.toString);<-----change 

JSONObject que1Obj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("q1")<------ like this
       String questionTitle = que1Obj.getString("question");
             JSONArray questionsArray =que1Obj.getJSONArray("options");
       String answer = que1Obj.getString("answer");






    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am getting a 'the method getJSONObject(string) is undefined for the type jsonobject' error using your above suggestion.

Comment: try  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject( obj.toString);

Comment: @AndrewClark check updated answer

Comment: toString cannot be resolved or is not a field